# Function causes variables passed by reference to behave unexpectedly

Tags: c, function, pointers, sdl, pass-by-reference

I have a C program that uses `SDL2`. I had a working program when the contents of `PenTool` were not in a function and were instead where the function is called, however putting it into a function has caused an issue I cannot get my head around. Avoiding global variables, I have passed all the variables I need to manipulate by reference including the function within PenTool, `bresline`. The code is supposed to draw a continuous line from the mouse by making the current mouse coords the end point and the previous mouse coords the start point of a line. However, in this functional layout, current mouse coords are recognized and drawn correctly on the screen, but previous mouse coords stay the same, resulting in every line drawn starting from the same point, instead of the actual previous mouse position. Furthermore, the print function shows all variables as unchanging while the mouse is moving, despite the running program drawing where my mouse is.

The issue is with `bresline`. When I comment it out, the print function shows all the variables updating correctly with mouse movement, so could someone please explain why `bresline` is preventing previous mouse coords from being assigned properly, and why it's preventing `printf` from showing correct mouse coords.

I have looked at other questions on StackOverflow and elsewhere on proper passing by reference and from what I can tell, I have passed my variables correctly and I don't know how to read **C++/Java** so those answers don't help, so I really don't know where I am going wrong.

```
void bresline(SDL_Renderer *,int *, int *, int *, int *, Uint32 *);
void PenTool(int, int *, int *, SDL_Point, int *, int *, SDL_Renderer *, Uint32 *);

int main(void)
{
    int mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, prevMouseX = 0, prevMouseY = 0;
    int penSize = 1;
...
    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
        if(leftMouseButtonDown)
        {
            PenTool(penSize, &mouseX, &mouseY, mouse_position, &prevMouseX, 
                &prevMouseY, renderer, pixels);
        }
...
void bresline(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int *x0, int *y0, int *xn, int *yn, Uint32 *pixels)
{
    int dx = abs(*xn-*x0), sx = *x0<*xn ? 1 : -1;
    int dy = abs(*yn-*y0), sy = *y0<*yn ? 1 : -1; 
    int error = (dx>dy ? dx : -dy)/2, e2;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    while(1)
    {
        pixels[*y0 * 1000 + *x0] = 0;
        if(*x0==*xn && *y0==*yn) break;
        e2 = error;
        if(e2 >-dx)
        {
            error -= dy;
            *x0 += sx;
        }
        if(e2 < dy)
        {
            error += dx;
            *y0 += sy;
        }
    }
}

void PenTool(int penSize, int *mouseX, int *mouseY, SDL_Point mouse_position, 
    int *prevMouseX, int *prevMouseY, SDL_Renderer *renderer, Uint32 *pixels)
{
    if(penSize == 1)
    {
        *mouseX = mouse_position.x;
        *mouseY = mouse_position.y;
        if((*prevMouseX == 0) && (*prevMouseY == 0))
        {
            *prevMouseX = *mouseX;
            *prevMouseY = *mouseY;
        }
        bresline(renderer, mouseX, mouseY, prevMouseX, prevMouseY, pixels);
        *prevMouseX = *mouseX;
        *prevMouseY = *mouseY;
        printf("M1_x: %d, M1_y: %d, M2_x: %d, M2_y: %d \n", *mouseX, *mouseY, *prevMouseX, *prevMouseY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try debugging your code .

Comment: @AtulKumar  In clang, I have used -Weverything and no warnings or errors come up during compilation. What other debugging solutions are there?

Comment: @User.Flynn -W options request static analysis, which is a separate thing from debugging. Debugging usually involves inspecting the behavior of the program as it actually runs. There are various tools to help with that, depending on your platform and compiler.

Comment: @AtulKumar Can you suggest any I could use for Linux/RedHat and Clang 5.0?

Comment: On a basic level put in as many calls to`printf` as you need to print the value of your variables as the program moves along.  When you see a value you don't expect, add more calls to `printf` between the last one that showed an expected value and the first one that showed an unexpected value.  Repeat until you identify exactly where the problem is.

Comment: @User.Flynn lldb could be a starting point, and this link could be a quick cheat sheet https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-command-examples.html happy debugging!

Comment: Make sure you are clear on what `x0` and `xn` are with respect to `mouseX` and `prevMouseX`. It wouldn't be unheard of to have them swapped somewhere.

Comment: On a pedantic note, there is no "pass by reference" in C - it is all "pass by value". You are simulating "pass by reference" by passing pointers.

Comment: @mlp I am aware of that, but for simplicity and because it's understood in context of C, our course calls it passing by reference anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, I would change bresline for:

```
void bresline(SDL_Renderer *,int , int , int , int , Uint32 *);

void bresline(SDL_Renderer *renderer, int x0, int y0, int xn, int yn, Uint32 *pixels)
{
    int dx = abs(xn-x0), sx = x0<xn ? 1 : -1;
    int dy = abs(yn-y0), sy = y0<yn ? 1 : -1; 
    int error = (dx>dy ? dx : -dy)/2, e2;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    while(1)
    {
        pixels[y0 * 1000 + x0] = 0;
        if(x0==xn && y0==yn) break;
        e2 = error;
        if(e2 >-dx)
        {
            error -= dy;
            x0 += sx;
        }
        if(e2 < dy)
        {
            error += dx;
            y0 += sy;
        }
    }
}
```

In your code you are changing the values inside the Bresenham's algorithm function, so that, MouseX and MouseY always will be PrevMouseX and PrevMouseY, when the function exit. That could explain your issue that always start the line from the same point.

---

And change how you do invoke the function for this:

```
bresline(renderer, *mouseX, *mouseY, *prevMouseX, *prevMouseY, pixels);
```

Comment: If I do this, my compiler warns that there's an incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'int *' to parameter type 'int'. Ignoring these warnings causes a segmentation fault when I click in the window.

Comment: If you change the types of the function arguments, you must change how the function is invoked so that they matches. By the way, I recommend you read more about pointers, references, pass values by reference and pass values by value. I think it could be useful for you.

Comment: Maybe this link can be useful: https://overiq.com/c-programming/101/call-by-value-and-call-by-reference-in-c/

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. Before your answer I had read a lot about passing by reference so I didn't think I was missing any knowledge but I see clearly now that I am. I will now study up more on this topic. Thanks for the suggested resource as well.